# How can I play a Sprite-Genie Hybrid character?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races

I am brand new to D&D (5e), and am starting to build my character.

Is there a way to be a sprite-genie hybrid PC? If so, how would that work, and could I grant wishes?

Comment: We are playing 5e.funny that you mention Tiefling, as that is what my friend wants to play as. I am not yet in contact with the DM. It is also to my understanding that this is his first time DMing. Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: Ray, thanks for clarifying, I have cast a vote to reopen your question.  Most DMs allow anything in the PHB, but some DMs have various options that are or are not available.  So it is very, very useful to contact the DM to find out if there are any options not available, or extra options available.

Comment: Thank you so much. My friend contacted the DM on my behalf and copied me on the email. So I should get a response.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

A Sprite and Genie both exist as creatures in the D&D 5e *Monster Manual*, but are not viable PC races.  A Hybrid of these two things does not exist in the rules.

As well, granting wishes is an extremely [high-level spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) (it's even described as “the mightiest spell a mortal creature can cast”), and it is unlikely your character would be able to do so early in the game.

I would recommend you check out the [Genasi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/genasi) player race (from the free-to-download [*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*](https://media.dnd.wizards.com/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf#page=7))  as this is most similar to what you have described. You could also take the [Custom Lineage from Tasha's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/tashas-cauldron-of-everything#CustomizingYourOrigin), and have your lineage be that of someone with a genie/sprite heritage.  There is also a [warlock subclass in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything based around being subservient to a Genie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/tashas-cauldron-of-everything#TheGenie), which may fit your character as well.  Something to discuss with your DM would be reskinning this class to fit what you are describing, while still remaining in the bounds of the game rules.

Comment: Greaat answer, I particularly like the suggestion of Genasi for maintaining that "genie" flavour the OP was after; what's more, if the OP hasn't yet decided on a class, they could still get the "fey" flavour  (alongside the "genie" flavour from being Genasi) by going Archfey Warlock (and if they pick Pact of the Tome, they could even literally have a sprite familiar). Of course, this all depends on what class the OP already had in mind...

Answer (score 2):

Almost anything is possible in D&D, and if you search hard enough, you just might find a homebrew race that fits your concept... or you can invent something yourself.

*However*, for a first-time player (& DM), I ***strongly*** recommend that you stick to official published content.

The closest official published race is the [Genasi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/genasi), as Jon suggested in his answer. They are half-genies. There are four subtypes, one for each element. Since you want something *spritely*, perhaps an Air Genasi would be your best choice - they get a bonus to dexterity, and can levitate once a day.